# MATLAB using parfor (parallel computing toolbox) and custom packages with +

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am working on a MATLAB program that users many other custom-made packages, often containing similarly-named files. So I have decided to use the custom package approach (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) to effectively get dot notation when referring to specific functions within the various packages I am using. For example, I have a package called `pose` that has this file structure:

```
MATLAB % on the MATLAB path
   --- +pose
          --- detect.m
          --- MORE STUFF
   --- +tracker
          --- MORE STUFF
   --- main.m
```

In my `main.m` file, I have a parallelized for loop:

```
parfor i=start:stop
    ... BLAH BLAH
    boxes = pose.detect(stuff);
    ... BLAH BLAH
end
```

But I keep getting the error that

MATLAB cannot determine whether "pose" refers to a
   function or variable.
   See Parallel for Loops in MATLAB, "Unambiguous Variable Names".

Looking at the MATLAB parallel programming documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/programming-considerations.html), it seems like all functions that you use inside a parallel for loop must be transparent inside the for loop. But this seems in direct violation of the other parallel programming principle in MATLAB, which is that "All workers executing a parfor-loop must have the same MATLAB search path as the client".

Does anyone know how to reconcile this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!

I did the solution from this webpage http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/share-code-with-the-workers.html by putting the path command in the worker startup file:
`matlabroot\toolbox\local\startup.m`

So I added the line `path('/custom_dir/MATLAB/', path);`, and it worked great.